# Why is JavaScript invalidating DOM references after I manipulate the body's innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, dom

I was messing around with some simple JS code and came across the following:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="div1">some text</div>';

var my_div = document.getElementById('div1');

document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="div2">some text</div>';

my_div.innerHTML = "some other text"; //doesn't work
```

It would seem that after manipulating the parent element (the body) the reference to the DOM node is invalidated. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does it work without the third row?

Comment: @Niklas yes and also if you swap the 2nd and the 3rd line around.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="div2">some text</div>';
```

it's the same as this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + '<div id="div2">some text</div>';
```

which as you can see replaces the whole of the body, recreating all the elements.

Comment: Thanks, RichieHindle!

Answer (score 2):

You are not "manipulating" the `innerHTML`, you are *overwriting* it!

When you use `+=` on `.innerHTML` the net result is that you end up *serialising* the entire DOM, appending the new string, and then *deserialising* the entire resulting HTML string back into DOM nodes.  In the process, all existing DOM nodes get destroyed.

IMHO, you should never use `.innerHTML` to *manipulate* DOM nodes, you should only use it to *create* them.

Comment: I understand the stupidity of what I'm doing. I should not use `.innerHTML` at all, except if for some reason I need to parse **row** HTML. For DOM purposes I'm better off using `document.createElement`

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="div1">some text</div>';

var my_div = document.getElementById('div1');

var div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.id = 'div2';
div2.innerHTML = 'some text';

my_div.parentNode.insertBefore(div2, my_div);

my_div.innerHTML = "some other text"; //work
```

Comment: it seems too easy to get it wrong that way. I was not considering how `.innerHTML` worked behind the scenes and couldn't understand the logic behind my browsers behavior. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

You should use like this, I think it will work fine.

```
    <body>

    </body>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="div1">some text</div>';

var my_div = document.getElementById('div1');

document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="div2">some text</div>';

my_div.innerHTML = "some other text"; //doesn't work
</script>
```