# setAttribute in for loop doesn't work as I expected

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

When user does any change in input, browser will loop all li tags with for loop and check what does it return when it tries indexOf(inputText). If indexOf returns -1, it need to filter it and don't show on the screen.

This is my simple HTML

```
<form>
....
  <div>
     <input type="text" name="ingredientSearch" placeholder="ingredients..">
  </div>
</form>
<div id="IngredientsList" class="noneDisplay">
  <ul>
      <li class="items">Apple</li>
      <li class="items">Asparagus</li>
      <li class="items">Baking Powder</li>
      <li class="items">Balsamic Vinegar</li>
      .......
      .......
      <li class="items">Vinegar</li>
      <li class="items">Wheat Flour</li>
      <li class="items">White Wine</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this is my javascript code.

```
function showListItems(){
let searchField=document.getElementsByName("ingredientSearch")[0];
let items = document.getElementsByClassName("items");
searchField.addEventListener("keyup",function(){
    if(document.getElementById("IngredientsList").hasAttribute("class","noneDisplay")){
        document.getElementById("IngredientsList").removeAttribute("class","noneDisplay");
    }
    filterListItems(items);
})
}

function filterListItems(items){
let inputText = document.getElementsByName("ingredientSearch")[0].value.toUpperCase();
for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    let itemsText = items[i].textContent.toUpperCase();
    if(itemsText.indexOf(inputText)==-1){
        items[i].setAttribute('class','noneDisplay');
    }else{
        items[i].removeAttribute('class','noneDisplay');
    }
}

}

showListItems();
```

class noneDisplay means css display:none

So my idea was if I type apple in input, browser will set class noneDisplay to all list items except the first one. If user types Strawberry, browser will set class noneDisplay to all list items except that list which has value Strawberry.

but this is what I get

[image]
[image]

it will be big thanks if you can help me without Jquery since I am trying it without it.

Comment: @Teemu. Fine. Understood why removeAttribute doesn't work correctly. But setAttribute also doesn't work as I thought..

Comment: Setting class attribute to some value makes the value to only class on that element, `removeAttribute` and `hasAttribute` take only a single argument. Then you would need `change` event attached to the input, to call `showListItems`, currently there's no value in the input at the time the function is executed.

Comment: Why don't you use Javascript to render the items as well ? I've created an example of a simpler way of doing this, if you don't mind changing your approach I can post the answer :)

Comment: @dev_junwen Actually, I rendered <li> tags with javascript. Rendering items happens before all these stuffs.. So I thought it's unnecessary to post rendering code here.

Comment: @dev_junwen But any help will be really grateful for me

Comment: @Teemu Thank you I finally understood why setAttribute did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer, I assumed that you are trying to modify the classes of an element. You can utilize [`classList`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp) property for that purposes. I've cleaned up some of your codes and formatted it.

```js
function showListItems() {
  const searchField = document.getElementsByName("ingredientSearch")[0];
  const items = document.getElementsByClassName("items");
  searchField.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    const ingredientsList = document.getElementById("IngredientsList");
    if (ingredientsList.classList.contains("noneDisplay")) {
      ingredientsList.classList.remove("noneDisplay");
    }
    filterListItems(items);
  });
}

function filterListItems(items) {
  const inputText = document.getElementsByName("ingredientSearch")[0].value.toUpperCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const itemsText = items[i].textContent.toUpperCase();
    if (itemsText.indexOf(inputText) > -1) {
      items[i].classList.remove("noneDisplay");
      continue;
    }
    items[i].classList.add("noneDisplay");
  }
}

showListItems();
```

As mentioned in the comments, I personally think that you can just filter and map based on an `items` array into a `ul` list, I think that way its simpler to do, easier to maintain and easier to read as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <body>
    <input id="input" placeholder="Search..." />
    <ul id="ingredients-list">
      <!-- List items will be created with javascript -->
    </ul>
    <script>
      const updateList = (items = []) => {
        const list = document.getElementById("ingredients-list");
        // Clear list items
        while (list.firstChild) {
          list.firstChild.remove();
        }
        if (items && Array.isArray(items) && items.length > 0) {
          // Rerender with new list items
          items.forEach(item => {
            const listItem = document.createElement("li");
            listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
            list.appendChild(listItem);
          });
        }
      };

      const handleOnChange = e => {
        const { value } = e.target;
        updateList(
          items.filter(item => item.toUpperCase().includes(value.toUpperCase()))
        );
      };

      const items = [
        "Apple",
        "Asparagus",
        "Baking Powder",
        "Balsamic Vinegar",
        "Vinegar",
        "Wheat Flour",
        "White Wine"
      ];

      updateList(items);

      const input = document.getElementById("input");
      input.addEventListener("keyup", handleOnChange);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Working Demo using my approach : https://codesandbox.io/s/html-filter-list-nolnk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @javaprogrammer You are welcome ! One thing I realize is that my codes doesn't seem to work very well in codesandbox.io. I am pretty sure it will work for any case ! Good luck coding :)

Comment: Hi again. I found a lot of threads and articles in google(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329507/why-is-javascript-invalidating-dom-references-after-i-manipulate-the-bodys-inne) (https://wpvip.com/documentation/vip-go/vip-code-review/javascript-security-best-practices/)  that innerHTML is risky for XSS attacks and textContent or innerText should be used instead. I tried using them, but they shows plain texts not html. is there any safer workaround for minimizing security issue?

Comment: @javaprogrammer Greetings. You can use Javascript to create `li` element, then with [`appendChild`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) to append to your list. It will clear your list and rerender with new list items every single text input onchange ( Which might affect performance ! ). I came from React background, so I am not too familiar with how to dynamically render html with plain Javascript haha. Using this should be much safer than using `innerHTML`.

Comment: @javaprogrammer I've updated my answer as well as the codesandbox. Feel free to check it out.